# Convergent sequence, such that if $nx_n\to a$ where $a\in\mathbb R$ then $\sqrt nx_n\to 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

I have this problem please give me a hint.

If $nx_n\to a$ where $a\in\mathbb R$ then $\sqrt nx_n\to 0$.

I have to show that $|\sqrt n x_n|<\epsilon$.

Since we have $|nx_n\to a|<\epsilon.$ i have no idea to make $|\sqrt n x_n|<\epsilon$.

Comment: $\sqrt n x_n = nx_n \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$. A convergent sequence is bounded.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Hey! That's **two** hints! :-)

Comment: Did you by chance mean $\sqrt{nx_n} \to 0$? (If so, then to enclose more than one character to be the argument of `\sqrt`, use "curly braces" to enclose the entire argument, like in the case *if* you mean $\sqrt{nx_n}$, use `\sqrt{nx_n}`.

Comment: @amWhy just $\sqrt n$

Comment: Good then.  Just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the $\epsilon$-$N$ definition, there are lots of [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Properties) of the limit of a sequence you can exploit.

You have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}nx_n=a,\quad \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=0.
$$
and thus
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(nx_n)\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=
\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}nx_n\right)\cdot \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=a\cdot 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
if $u > v$,
$x_n > 0$,
and
$n^ux_n$ is bounded,
then
$n^v x_n \to 0$.

Your question is the case
$u = 1, v = 1/2$.

Proof:

Since
$n^u x_n$ is bounded,
there is a $b > 0$
such that
$n^ux_n < b$.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
n^vx_n
&=n^{u+(v-u)}x_n\\
&=n^ux_nn^{v-u}\\
&=\dfrac{n^ux_n}{n^{u-v}}\\
&<\dfrac{b}{n^{u-v}}\\
&\to 0
\qquad\text{since } u-v > 0
\text{ so } n^{u-v} \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$